# How to access **state** outside of BlocBuilder?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

I'm doing a meal-recipe App in which I am wrapping  in a BlocBuilder as below:

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("The Recipe Bloc"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.orange[800],
      ),
      body: Center(child: BlocBuilder<RecipeCubit, RecipeState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is RecipeInitial) {
            return const CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.orange);
          }
          if (state is RecipeLoaded) {
            return state.recipeList.isEmpty
                ? const Center(child: Text("No Recipes Registered Yet!"))
                : ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: state.recipeList.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return RecipeListTile(parentContext: context, recipeItem: state.recipeList[index]).display;
                    });
          } else {
            // In Case The App Reads from Outside of Standard States
            return const Text("Something Went Wrong!");
          }
        },
      )),

      //Add New Recipes
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: Colors.orange[800],
          onPressed: () {
            List<Recipe> outofContext_recipeList =context.select((value) => null)
            showDialog(context: context, builder: (BuildContext context) => CreateRecipeDialog(lastID: state.recipeList.isNotEmpty ? state.recipeList.last.id : "-1"));
          },
          child: const Icon(Icons.add_rounded)),
    );
  }
}
```

regardless of options I put in the screen, I want to have a **FloatingActionButton()** for adding new recipes.

So here comes my question, How can I access my **CubitState/state** outside of **BlocBuilder**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey to get the state of your `Recipe Cubit` you can use

```
context.read<RecipeCubit>().state
```

or

```
BlocProvider.of<RecipeCubit>(context).state
```

anyone can be used as per your preference to get the state of your `Recipe Cubit` outside the BlocBuilder.

Comment: It work like I wanted. Although it's gonna be a problem with MULTIPLE CONTEXT, It's simple and doesn't add much load to the app unlike using another BlocBuilder/BlocConsumer for FloadtingActionButton. Thanks @Priyanshu

Comment: I am happy, I was able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

There can be 3 approaches which you can use:

**First Approach: Wrapping Floating Action Button with `BlocBuilder`**

- Wrap the floating action button with `BlocBuilder`.
- This allows the button to instantly use data from the current state.
- No need to store data separately; it's readily available.

'''

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
const HomeScreen({super.key});

@override
State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
   resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
   appBar: AppBar(
     title: const Text("The Recipe Bloc"),
     backgroundColor: Colors.orange[800],
   ),
   body: Center(child: BlocBuilder<RecipeCubit, RecipeState>(
     builder: (context, state) {
       if (state is RecipeInitial) {
        return const CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.orange);
       }
       if (state is RecipeLoaded) {
        return state.recipes.isEmpty
            ? const Center(child: Text("No Recipes Registered Yet!"))
            : ListView.builder(
                itemCount: state.recipes.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return RecipeListTile(parentContext: context, recipeItem: state.recipes[index]).display;
                });
      } else {
        // In Case The App Reads from Outside of Standard States
        return const Text("Something Went Wrong!");
      }
    },
  )),

  //Add New Recipes
  floatingActionButton: BlocBuilder<RecipeCubit, RecipeState>(
    builder: (context, state) {
      if (state is RecipeLoaded) {
        return FloatingActionButton(
            backgroundColor: Colors.orange[800],
            onPressed: () {
              showDialog(context: context, builder: (BuildContext context) => CreateRecipeDialog(lastID: state.recipes.isNotEmpty ? state.recipes.last.id : "-1"));
            },
            child: const Icon(Icons.add_rounded));
        } else {
         return Container();
       }
     },
    ),
  );
 }
}
```

'''

**Second Approach: Using `BlocConsumer` and Listener**

- Initialize an empty list for recipes.
- Use `BlocConsumer` with a `listener` to update the recipes list when state changes.
- Build UI components based on different states using the `builder` function.
- Floating action button works similarly to the first approach.

'''

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
const HomeScreen({super.key});

@override
State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
 List<Recipe> recipes = [];

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
   resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
   appBar: AppBar(
     title: const Text("The Recipe Bloc"),
     backgroundColor: Colors.orange[800],
   ),
   body: Center(
       child: BlocConsumer<RecipeCubit, RecipeState>(
         listener: (context,state) {
           if(state is RecipeLoaded) {
             recipes = state.recipes;
           }
         },
         builder: (context, state) {
           if (state is RecipeInitial) {
             return const CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.orange);
           }
           if (state is RecipeLoaded) {
             return state.recipes.isEmpty
                 ? const Center(child: Text("No Recipes Registered Yet!"))
                 : ListView.builder(
                 itemCount: state.recipes.length,
                 itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                   return RecipeListTile(parentContext: context, recipeItem: state.recipes[index]).display;
                 });
           } else {
             // In Case The App Reads from Outside of Standard States
             return const Text("Something Went Wrong!");
           }
         },
       )),

   //Add New Recipes
   floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
       backgroundColor: Colors.orange[800],
       onPressed: () {
         /// you can show snack bar here if the recipes list is empty by using if else condition or you can continue with as per your requirement
         showDialog(context: context, builder: (BuildContext context) => CreateRecipeDialog(lastID: recipes.isNotEmpty ? recipes.last.id : "-1"));
       },
       child: const Icon(Icons.add_rounded)),
 );
 }
}
```

'''
**Third Approach: Using `BlocProvider.of` and State**

- Build UI with `BlocBuilder`.
- When the button is pressed, directly access current state with `BlocProvider.of<RecipeCubit>(context).state`.
- If the state is `RecipeLoaded`, show the dialog with state's data.
- Otherwise, handle the situation as needed.

'''

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
const HomeScreen({super.key});

@override
State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
   resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
   appBar: AppBar(
     title: const Text("The Recipe Bloc"),
     backgroundColor: Colors.orange[800],
   ),
   body: Center(child: BlocBuilder<RecipeCubit, RecipeState>(
     builder: (context, state) {
       if (state is RecipeInitial) {
         return const CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.orange);
       }
       if (state is RecipeLoaded) {
         return state.recipes.isEmpty
             ? const Center(child: Text("No Recipes Registered Yet!"))
             : ListView.builder(
             itemCount: state.recipes.length,
             itemBuilder: (context, index) {
               return RecipeListTile(parentContext: context, recipeItem: state.recipes[index]).display;
             });
       } else {
         // In Case The App Reads from Outside of Standard States
         return const Text("Something Went Wrong!");
       }
     },
   )),

   //Add New Recipes
   floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
       backgroundColor: Colors.orange[800],
       onPressed: () {
         RecipeState recipeState = BlocProvider.of<RecipeCubit>(context).state;
         if(recipeState is RecipeLoaded) {
           showDialog(context: context, builder: (BuildContext context) => CreateRecipeDialog(lastID: recipeState.recipes.isNotEmpty ? recipeState.recipes.last.id : "-1"));
         } else {
           /// you can show snack bar here if the recipes list is empty by using if else condition or you can continue with as per your requirement
         }
       },
       child: const Icon(Icons.add_rounded)),
 );

 }
}
```

**Summary:**

- The first approach simplifies by allowing direct state access via `BlocBuilder`.
- The second approach manages state and updates a recipes list using `BlocConsumer`.
- The third approach streamlines by using `BlocProvider.of` to interact directly with the state.

All three approaches offer solutions to display and add recipes, catering to different coding preferences and app requirements.

Comment: First let me thank you for your complete answer! I feel like you covered all answers there was for my problem. There are few things I want to add. Regarding usage of BlocBuilder/BlocConsumer for FloadtingActionButton in 1th & 2th approach, I think it's gonna be too big of an answer for this problem. If this page had some title that needed re-build after user-action, BlocBuilder was my best guess too but I just want to use the last recipe_item's **Index** in the list and that's it!

Comment: About using BlocConsumer to wrap the whole Center() Widget you still need to setState a state from StatefulWidget in the **listener** field and doing so would be not so simple anymore. Although I'm inspired by the first approach and might use it later in my app, I believe second approach is not gonna work for me. The third approach is gonna be my favorite in this case. It's doesn't add a heavy load to the app and it sure keeps the work quick and simple! @sanchit Thanks for helping me!

Comment: @DavidBlack Yes you are right about your approach and yes use cases for flutter_bloc vary a lot and it totally depends on the situation we are working on. I just listed few of the example in ways we can use BlocBuilder and BlocConsumer. I'm happy that you got your answer.